# Javascript. get all element by aria-label

Tags: javascript

Hey im trying to get every single element on a page that has an aria label that contains/starts with "i_". I also need to do this in javascript.

thanks

Comment: So what have you tried so far? What problems are you having with your existing source code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In CSS, you would use the [`[attribute^=value]`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp) format:

```
[aria-label^="i_"] {
    background: #55ff55;
}
```

In JavaScript, just use the same thing:

```
document.querySelectorAll("[aria-label^='i_']");
```

That should return an array-like list of all the elements with `aria-label` values that start with `i_`.

Here's an example with both of them:

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll("[aria-label^='i_']");
// 'x' contains all of the <p> elements that have "i_" in the start
```

```css
[aria-label^="i_"] {
    background: #55ff55;
}
```

```html
<p aria-label="i_foo"> Giraffes have black tongues to protect them from getting sunburnt </p>
<p aria-label="i_bar"> Coral colonies can live up to centuries old </p>
<p aria-label="m_foo"> The moon is a planet </p>
<p aria-label="i_gaw"> Ostriches' eyes are larger than their brains </p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Catch all specified elements, iterate over them and check if it's `aria-label` attribute starts with `i_`. If so - push it into newly made `arr`.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('elem');
var arr = [];

Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.getAttribute('aria-label').startsWith('i_') ? arr.push(v) : v);

console.log(arr);
```

```html
<div aria-label='i_one' class='elem'></div>
<div aria-label='i_two' class='elem'></div>
<div aria-label='three' class='elem'></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the document.querySelector[All] method to find your element by css. With css you can filter by attributes. `*[aria-label^="value"]` would select any elements that have an aria-label which it's value starts with "value".

code:

```
const node = document.querySelector('*[aria-label^="containing"]');
```